# errorCode": "APEX_ERROR", "message": "System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null

Tags: apex, rest-api

If i pass date i am able to execute first if condition but if parameter is not passed in URL from postman, i am getting Null pointer exception error.

```
RestRequest restReq = RestContext.request; 
           // Reading parametrs from URL
        dt = restReq.params.get('date');
           Date d = Date.parse(dt);          
 if(!String.isBlank(dt)){

            Record  =  [SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE  E >= :d];

           }

           if(String.isBlank(dt)){


                   Record  =  [SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE E >= :date.today()-7];

           }
```

Comment: are you sure that you are getting the error in this piece of code? It seems fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `null` to `Date.parse()` method. So, you have to validate it before passing to the `parse` method.

```java
RestRequest restReq = RestContext.request;
String dt = restReq.params.get('date');

if (String.isNotBlank(dt)) {
    Date d = Date.parse(dt);
    Record  =  [SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE  E >= :d];
    // OR
    Record  =  [SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE E >= :date.today()-7];
}
else {
    // handle validation
}
```

Comment: Great it working now. Thanks Raman, Cheers!!